# Hyperledger Fabric - Core.yaml

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I see a lot of examples for Hyperledger Fabric where I don't find core.yaml file in all examples. I see a lot of other files. And at many places, core.yaml is referred. Is there any other file, that corresponds to it?
From where this, core.yaml config is picked? How should I use it?

Comment: I think we'll need a little more detail here. First, "I don't find core.yaml file in all examples", what do you mean by "examples"? Do you mean fabric-samples? If not, where are you finding these examples?

Comment: @ajp Yes, I was referring to fabric-samples.

Answer (score 7):

`core.yaml` file provides basic configuration option for various peer modules. For example it is capable of configuring logging level, e.g.:

```
###############################################################################
logging:

    cauthdsl:   warning
    gossip:     warning
    ledger:     info
    msp:        warning
    policies:   warning
    grpc:       error
```

Now, the reason you do not see this file within fabric-sample, because it has been already packed into peer docker container and therefore simple a part of it. Next, since Hyperledger Fabric uses [viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) to read the configuration and viper initialed with:

```
// For environment variables.
viper.SetEnvPrefix("core")
viper.AutomaticEnv()
replacer := strings.NewReplacer(".", "_")
viper.SetEnvKeyReplacer(replacer)
```

Which make it possible to override and control configuration parameters by exporting them via environment variables prefixed with `CORE`.

Comment: Thank You for replying. Okay. I got the point. So, Let's say if I provide the value of any parameter via environment variable, and start the peers, then If I go inside the docker image, then also, I won't see the value I provided via variable. It will still hold the value actually present in packed core.yaml. Am I correct?

Comment: Not really, actually if you have updated environment variable, once entering the container you will see updated value. However core.yaml will contain default or original value.

Comment: You can try it with build your first network example

Comment: Yes, I tried it. So, container does have it. Thank You ! Thumbs up !

Comment: More info here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/commands/peernode.html

Answer (score 1):

core.yaml corresponds to a older version of Hyperledger Fabric, to the version 0.6. There, you defined the Peer configuration.

In the v1.0 Hyperledger Fabric, the docker-compose-file.yaml seem to be the same.

Comment: If this is true, as of v1.1.0-alpha the Peer package main() function seems to still try to find the core.yaml file:  `const cmdRoot = "core"`, `err := common.InitConfig(cmdRoot)`, and `var mspMgrConfigDir = config.GetPath("peer.mspConfigPath")`, along with some others...

Comment: But @Urko, you are correct that the docker-compose file can be used to override the core.yaml setup.